# How to combine dynamic ranges with OFFSET and INDIRECT functions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a formula that uses a dynamic range to link to the different tabs. It would then return the last 12 values before a blank cell, based on the value in the Header Column.

The tricky part is the data in each tab is of different sizes, so I thought it might have to incorporate either `Offset(Blank()),0,-12)` or something of the sort. I've tried a lot of different things, and this is the latest effort:

```
=Index(Indirect(A2&"!A9:AK9"),match("Conversions",Indirect(A2&"!A9:AK9"),)0,-12)
```

Edit: First post, sorry for the confusion. My goal is to make a large dashboard that has a dynamic chart using our monthly metrics. (I'm leaving the chart setup for another day)

The data varies in such, some have columns A:K, while some have a larger range of A:AK , etc. (With A:A being text). Since I've posted this, I have had some success by using Filter(), but *the problem I'm not sure how to solve is finding the last 12 values before a blank cell*.

[Example of Data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C4FP.png)

[Example of Data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfXBq.png)

Hopefully this helps explain the situation and I appreciate everyone for help.

Comment: You need to provide some idea of what the data looks like (text vs numbers vs dates vs blanks) and what you plan to do with *'the last 12 values before a blank cell'*.

Comment: @John Welcome. Have you resolved your Google Sheet problem, or are you still looking for help?

Comment: @user10829321 Sorry about that. I've added an image and tried to add more detail. Thanks for taking the time to let me know!